# .gitignore Files Still Show Up in Untracked List

Tags: git

I have some files that were being tracked by Git:

- content/.htaccess
- admin/cache/
- db_changes.docx

But then I decided I wanted Git to ignore them. So I added them to the .gitignore file, then ran these commands:

```
git rm --cached content/.htaccess
git rm -r --cached admin/cache/
git rm --cached db_changes.docx
```

Then I committed the repo. But if I run `git status` again, those files still show up in the "untracked files" list.

I ran:

```
git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others
```

to list .gitignore files, but nothing showed up. I'm sure I put them in the .gitignore file correctly, so I'm really confused/frustrated.

Comment: What exactly does your .gitignore say and where is it located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `.gitignore` file was in the wrong place. I had it in the root of my `.git` directory, not the root of my repo.